# Which form of the verb "come" is correct?

Tags: verbs, questions, subject-verb-agreement

"Does creativity **comes** with insanity?"

OR

"Does creativity **come** with insanity?"

Which of the above sentence is grammatically correct and why? What effect does using the word “Does” causes on the verb usage in the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Does - come is correct.

Verb after does or do should be its original word.